# Bulk Extrator Via APi

Tags: import.io

I have built an Extractor with the UI on windows. I have multiple pages so i have chosen bulk extractor. I fed around 10+ urls and click query. Great everything works, comes out beautiful.

However i go over to export and want to start learning how to export this bulk extractor of urls to the API. I hit simple API, this only displays the results of the first bulk url.

How can i make a call to multiple urls within the same API call so the results are all in one page rather than multiple api calls?

I am trying to at some point bring all this data via php into my MySQL database periodically (daily).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keelan,

- The bad news: at the moment it is not possible to run bulk extract as an API
- The good news: we are working on it right now! Actually, if you want to get in touch with us, we'd love to add you to the beta users for the new feature

Comment: I will hit up suppprt! Thanks.